# flatten a structure where the elements can be an object or a nested array

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON document that I would like to flatten where I get a resultant object resemling this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Form/Field/Tokens.php",
    "line": "62",
    "severity": "info",
    "message": "Expected @param annotation",
    "source": "PhanCommentParamOutOfOrder"
  }
]
```

In order to do this, I would need to flatten the `file` object but different ones represent the nested `error` node as an object or an array. I'm not sure how to flatten it.

Here's the given document.

```
{
  "version": "6.5",
  "file": [
    {
      "name": "Form/Field/Tokens.php",
      "error": {
        "line": "62",
        "severity": "info",
        "message": "Expected @param annotation",
        "source": "PhanCommentParamOutOfOrder"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Console/Command/Reference.php",
      "error": [
        {
          "line": "40",
          "severity": "warning",
          "message": "Possibly zero references to use statement",
          "source": "PhanUnreferencedUseNormal"
        },
        {
          "line": "54",
          "severity": "warning",
          "message": "Property has undeclared type",
          "source": "PhanUndeclaredTypeProperty"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What should the flattened Reference.php node look like? Split into multiple objects with the same name, each with a separate error or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given JQ's `type` builtin, you just need an if-then-else expression to determine if `.file.error` is an array or an object.

```
.file | map({name} + (.error |
  if type == "array" then .[] else . end))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AwWDav1O4_)</sup>